# clickable text in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, clickable

I want to make a text in `alert dialog` which is clickable. actually the text will be an ID. so when you click it, it will open browser and go to a specific webpage. how should I do it?
his is my code:

```
alertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
mBuilder.setMessage("@sampleID");
mBuilder.setCancelable(true);
AlertDialog mAlert = mBuilder.create();
mAlert.show();
```

also, how can I put multiple lines in the alert dialog?(different id's at each line)

Comment: Use a custom Dialog(Fragment) with a ListView.

Comment: As far as I know, a dialog should avoid opening another dialog or another webpage from inside. This is not a best practice. Please check the Material Design [documentation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs)! It states, *Dialogs should not include more than two actions. A third action, such as “Learn more,” navigates away from the dialog, potentially leaving the task unfinished. Avoid using a “Learn more” action to access help documentation; in-line expansion within the dialog should be used instead.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a layout contains what you want and use setContentView to add the layout to AlertDialog.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_custom, null);
TextView tv1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.your_item_0);
tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener());
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
dialog.getWindow().setContentView(layout);
```